How to create a folder action that copies itself into new sub-folders?
I'm indexing my mac with the color tags and I want a folder action to copy itself into new sub-folders so it automatically keeps tagging sub-folders.
I don't want it to prompt but just to let it assign a specific folder action.
I found this 'Attach Script to Folder' script in the example scripts folder (/Library/Scripts/Folder Actions/):
property ChooseScriptPrompt : "Select compiled script file(s) containing folder actions"
property ChooseFolderPrompt : "Select a folder to attach actions"
property ErrorMsg : " is not a compiled script. (Ignored)."


on open DroppedItems
    choose folder with prompt ChooseFolderPrompt
    set TargetFolder to the result as text
    tell application "Finder" to ¬
        set FAName to name of alias TargetFolder
    tell application "System Events"
        if folder action FAName exists then
            --Don't make a new one
        else
            make new folder action ¬
                at end of folder actions ¬
                with properties {path:TargetFolder} -- name:FAName, 
        end if
    end tell
    
    repeat with EachItem in DroppedItems
        set ItemInfo to info for EachItem
        if not folder of ItemInfo then
            set FileTypeOfItem to file type of ItemInfo
            set FileExtensionOfItem to name extension of ItemInfo
            set ItemName to name of ItemInfo
            if FileTypeOfItem is "osas" or FileExtensionOfItem is "scpt" then
                tell application "System Events"
                    tell folder action FAName
                        make new script ¬
                            at end of scripts ¬
                            with properties {name:ItemName}
                    end tell
                end tell
            else
                display dialog ItemName & ErrorMsg with icon caution
            end if
        end if
    end repeat
end open

on run
    my ChooseFileFromFAScriptFolder()
    open the result
end run


to ChooseFileFromFAScriptFolder()
    try
        set LibraryScripts to list folder (path to Folder Action scripts folder from local domain) without invisibles
    on error
        set LibraryScripts to {}
    end try
    try
        set UserScripts to list folder (path to Folder Action scripts folder from user domain) without invisibles
    on error
        set UserScripts to {}
    end try
    if (count LibraryScripts) + (count UserScripts) is greater than 0 then
        set ChosenScripts to choose from list LibraryScripts & UserScripts with prompt ChooseScriptPrompt ¬
            with multiple selections allowed
        if class of ChosenScripts is boolean then
            error number -128
        else
            set SelectedScripts to {}
            repeat with EachScript in ChosenScripts
                if EachScript is in LibraryScripts then
                    copy alias ((path to Folder Action scripts folder from local domain as Unicode text) & EachScript) to end of SelectedScripts
                else if EachScript is in UserScripts then
                    copy alias ((path to Folder Action scripts folder from user domain as Unicode text) & EachScript) to end of SelectedScripts
                end if
            end repeat
            return SelectedScripts
        end if
    end if
    return {}
end ChooseFileFromFAScriptFolder

How to tell the TargetFolder is the last new created or placed folder in the ParentFolder?

What do you mean by "automatically keeps tagging sub-folders"?  Folder actions don't get copied, they are typically stored in the ~/Library/Scripts/Folder Action Scripts folder and the specified folder action is attached to the target folder.  From there the folder action would be triggered when something gets added to that folder.
